# File shortcut to a dash home entry?

Tags: 12.04, unity-dash, shortcuts

I want to have users click on a file in ubuntu 12.04 and have that open the "installed applications" menu in dash home. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: a pitty your question isn't about 14.04 :)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible, as the application menu in the dash is a lens.  However, it's possible to show all installed applications by creating a desktop file containing a link to the application directory.

Create the following file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Link
Name=Applications
Comment=All installed Ubuntu Applications
URL=file:///user/share/applications/
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/debian-logo.png
```

Save it wherever you want it to be with a `.desktop` extension and double-click it...

You're not going to like the result as it shows *all* installed applications (including some that are not in the application lens), but that's as close as you'll get to what you asked...

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: I have to test this...

Comment: "Save it wherever you want it to be and double-click it" seems to be wrong. Is this a Unity thing?

Comment: @A.B. Should work anywhere: I use this system on Ubuntu and Lubuntu...  This just opens the standard file manager inside the directory that is in the desktop file.  (a bit like Windows .lnk files)